# Recommendation for a RTE that puts designers first

Tags: html-editor

**What I'm looking for:** I'm looking for a paid/free HTML rich text editor that allows the user to create boxes or shapes as our designer calls them, but really `div` elements with a multitude of easy to apply CSS options. The ability to add background colors to them, shadows, etc. The editor should also have the standard image and editing abilities. I'm looking for an RTE that puts the designer first almost.

**What it's for:** Our newest company project is a CMS for businesses. Almost an easy to use WordPress so to speak. However most of our clients will add limited content and our design team will be doing a bulk of the inner page work using it. They asked for an editor than can easily create and style HTML elements without knowing code.

**Background:** I'm not asking without the full day worth of research, trial and error. We have fully integrated and customized [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) and [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for past projects but they lack what this project needs. Out of all the editors I came across the closest I could find was [Raptor Editor](https://www.raptor-editor.com/).

Does anyone have any recommendations they may know about?

Comment: Have you tried using LibraOffice and exporting to html?

Comment: You can also take a look at the [Nevron text editor](https://docs.nevron.com/products-text-editor-free-text-editor.aspx) it has pretty amazing capabilities to work with HTML. Unfortunately it doesn't have any interactive image formatting. However you can format images programmatically with their [commercial version](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-rich-text-editor-control-overview.aspx) of the text editor.